# Populating a listbox in a mock invoice with selected items

Tags: c#, beginner, winforms

So I'm almost 100% certain I've done something wrong simply due to the inefficiency of what I've written, I'm entirely a novice to coding and am working on an assignment for my introductory programming course. The only way I could think to display the input from 4 check boxes was to go down 16 different branches to cover every possible input option, is there any simpler or quicker way to show the results on a listbox? This project is for a mock cruise invoice

```
        //Onboard services expense clarification//
        int finedining;
        finedining = int.Parse("200");

        int fitnesstrainer;
        fitnesstrainer = int.Parse("50");

        decimal excursions;
        excursions = decimal.Parse("399.9");

        decimal airporttransfer;
        airporttransfer = decimal.Parse("45.5");

        decimal noservices;
        noservices = decimal.Parse("0.00");


        //Check Box Data//
        if (diningCheckBox.Checked && !fitnessCheckBox.Checked && !excursionsCheckBox.Checked && !airportCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            titlesListBox.Items.Add("Fine Dining");
            valueListBox.Items.Add(finedining);
        }
        else if (diningCheckBox.Checked && fitnessCheckBox.Checked && !excursionsCheckBox.Checked && !airportCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            titlesListBox.Items.Add("Fine Dining, Fitness Trainer");
            valueListBox.Items.Add(finedining + fitnesstrainer);
        }
        else if (diningCheckBox.Checked && fitnessCheckBox.Checked && excursionsCheckBox.Checked && !airportCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            titlesListBox.Items.Add("Fine Dining, Fitness Trainer, Excursions");
            valueListBox.Items.Add(finedining + fitnesstrainer + excursions);
        }
        else if (diningCheckBox.Checked && fitnessCheckBox.Checked && excursionsCheckBox.Checked && airportCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            titlesListBox.Items.Add("Fine Dining, Fitness Trainer, Excursions, Airport Transfer");
            valueListBox.Items.Add(finedining + fitnesstrainer + excursions + airporttransfer);
        }
        else if (diningCheckBox.Checked && !fitnessCheckBox.Checked && excursionsCheckBox.Checked && airportCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            titlesListBox.Items.Add("Fine Dining, Excursions, Airport Transfer");
            valueListBox.Items.Add(finedining + excursions + airporttransfer);
        }
        else if (diningCheckBox.Checked && fitnessCheckBox.Checked && !excursionsCheckBox.Checked && airportCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            titlesListBox.Items.Add("Fine Dining, Fitness Trainer, Airport Transfer");
            valueListBox.Items.Add(finedining + fitnesstrainer + airporttransfer);
        }
        else if (diningCheckBox.Checked && !fitnessCheckBox.Checked && !excursionsCheckBox.Checked && airportCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            titlesListBox.Items.Add("Fine Dining, Airport Transfer");
            valueListBox.Items.Add(finedining + airporttransfer);
        }
        else if (diningCheckBox.Checked && !fitnessCheckBox.Checked && excursionsCheckBox.Checked && !airportCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            titlesListBox.Items.Add("Fine Dining, Excursions");
            valueListBox.Items.Add(finedining + excursions);
        }
        else if (!diningCheckBox.Checked && fitnessCheckBox.Checked && excursionsCheckBox.Checked && airportCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            titlesListBox.Items.Add("Fitness Trainer, Excursions, Airport Transfer");
            valueListBox.Items.Add(fitnesstrainer + excursions + airporttransfer);
        }
        else if (!diningCheckBox.Checked && fitnessCheckBox.Checked && excursionsCheckBox.Checked && !airportCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            titlesListBox.Items.Add("Fitness Trainer, Excursions");
            valueListBox.Items.Add(fitnesstrainer + excursions);
        }
        else if (!diningCheckBox.Checked && fitnessCheckBox.Checked && !excursionsCheckBox.Checked && airportCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            titlesListBox.Items.Add("Fitness Trainer, Airport Transfer");
            valueListBox.Items.Add(fitnesstrainer + airporttransfer);
        }
        else if (!diningCheckBox.Checked && fitnessCheckBox.Checked && !excursionsCheckBox.Checked && !airportCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            titlesListBox.Items.Add("Fitness Trainer");
            valueListBox.Items.Add(fitnesstrainer);
        }
        else if (!diningCheckBox.Checked && !fitnessCheckBox.Checked && excursionsCheckBox.Checked && airportCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            titlesListBox.Items.Add("Excursions, Airport Transfer");
            valueListBox.Items.Add(excursions + airporttransfer);
        }
        else if (!diningCheckBox.Checked && !fitnessCheckBox.Checked && excursionsCheckBox.Checked && !airportCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            titlesListBox.Items.Add("Excursions");
            valueListBox.Items.Add(excursions);
        }
        else if (!diningCheckBox.Checked && !fitnessCheckBox.Checked && !excursionsCheckBox.Checked && airportCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            titlesListBox.Items.Add("Airport Transfer");
            valueListBox.Items.Add(airporttransfer);
        }
        else if (!diningCheckBox.Checked && !fitnessCheckBox.Checked && !excursionsCheckBox.Checked && !airportCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            titlesListBox.Items.Add("No onboard services requested");
            valueListBox.Items.Add(noservices);``
```

Comment: Where is this code located exactly? It seems to be living in a form's code-behind.. is it in some `Click` handler for some `Ok` button?

Comment: The code is from a button click to compile the results of all imputed data onto a listbox. If this question isn't intended for this site I'm sorry I'm not quite sure where to ask it nor where to find the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments:

> *The code is from a button click to compile the results of all imputed data onto a listbox.*

It's not the job of a button's `Click` handler to to all that work... and the *work* in question should be much, much simpler ;-)

How?

Your approach is very prone to bugs and errors, and writing a test to programmatically ensure that this complicated logic works as intended, is pretty much impossible.

Create an abstraction to represent any of the items - think in terms of *objects* here, ask yourself *what's common to all these things?* - the answer is probably something along these lines:

```
public class PackageItem
{
    public PackageItem(string description, decimal price)
    { 
        Description = description;
        Price = price;
    }  

    bool IsIncluded { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

You'd have a class like this for each item that's possible to select - notice how the type of `Price` doesn't need to change from `int` to `decimal` if you go on a 30% sale.. don't pick a type for its value, pick a type for its usage: currency should be `decimal`, regardless of whether the value is `200` or `199.99`.

By using a class to encapsulate this concept, you're making sure that the `Price` is always going to be a `decimal` - that will avoid quite a few headaches when comes the time to tally up the bill.

Then you would make a "model" for your form, that would include a list of all possible items:

```
private PackageItem _excursions = new PackageItem("Excursion",399.9);
private PackageItem _fineDining = new PackageItem("Fine dining", 200);
private PackageItem _fitnessTraining = new PackageItem("Fitness trainer", 50);
private PackageItem _airportTransfer = new PackageItem("Airport transfer", 45.5);
```

Now, when a checkbox' `Checked` value changes, you can toggle the corresponding item's `IsIncluded` property:

```
private void diningCheckBox_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _fineDining.IsIncluded = diningCheckBox.Checked;
}

private void fitnessCheckBox_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _fitnessTraining.IsIncluded = fitnessCheckBox.Checked;
}

//...
```

---

Your approach for adding the descriptions into the `titlesListBox` suggests that a simple `TextBox` would have worked just as well, since you're only ever adding a single string to that list.

Consider simply iterating your `PackageItem` objects and adding an item whenever it's included - your click handler could be as simple as this:

```
var items = new[] { _excursions, _fineDining, _fitnessTraining, _airportTransfer };
foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (item.IsIncluded)
    {
        titlesListBox.Add(item.Description);
        valueListBox.Add(item.Price);
    }
}
```

From there, computing the total value should be a breeze.

Notice that the click handler doesn't care about the *checkboxes* - it's only looking at *abstractions* representing whatever these checkboxes stand for.

It's not *Model-View-Presenter* yet, but it would be a good step in the right direction I think.

I've left out the "No services" item for you to figure out.